# A device with HID interface

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, hid

I have got application that work with usb barcode scanner.

Value from scanner is put to **`EditText`**.

I don't want show **`EditText`**, but get value from scanner.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of the EditText in xml as `invisible` as simple as that. you can still get values from it. (OR) Don't set the value from barcode to the edit text.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put Invisible or gone. I prefer gone because it occupies no space in UI.

```
editTextRef.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I dont understand why you can not save the value in a variable.

Comment: It is working with HID interface, so value is automatically put to focused view.

Comment: @Unmerciful , okay got it . I believe its library and you cannot change that part of code.